# How to include dependencies from tests classes and main executable class in one jar

Tags: java, gradle, testng, selenide

I am trying to create an executable jar that will launch my selenide test.

**TestClass**

```
public class TestClass {

    @Test
    public void openBrowser(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chrome location");
        open("google.com");
    }
}
```

**Test Executor**

```
public class TestExecutor {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
        TestNG testng = new TestNG();
        testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { TestClass.class });
        testng.addListener((ITestNGListener) tla);
        testng.run(); 

    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url = 'jfrog artifactory url'
    }
}
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar
task testJar(type: ShadowJar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle',
                'Implementation-Version': project.version,
                'Main-Class': 'TestExecutor'
    }
    from sourceSets.test.output
    configurations = [project.configurations.testRuntime]
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
 }



dependencies {
    testCompile  'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.141.59'
    testCompile   'org.apache.poi:poi:4.1.0'
    testCompile   'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.1.0'
    testCompile  'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.5'
    testCompile   group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: '5.5.2'
    testCompile  group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-params', version: '5.5.2'
    testCompile   group: 'com.codeborne', name: 'selenide', version: '5.1.0'
    testCompile   group: 'com.aventstack', name: 'extentreports', version: '4.0.9'
    testCompile  group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-engine', version: '5.5.2'
    testCompile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '6.14.3'

    compile  group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '6.14.3'
}


group 'groupId'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
```

when building the jar it cannot find the test dependencies.

I have tried adding the testRuntimeClasspath to the jar like so

```
  from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
        configurations.testRuntimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
```

but then I receive an error saying **Could not find or load main class**

I've been going at trying to get this running for 2+ weeks. I don't know what I need to do really because all this is new to me. SEND HELP.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [Gradle Shadow JAR plugin](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow), instead of creating a JAR with all transitive dependencies youself. They even have [the exact example for this case in the docs](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/custom-tasks):

```
// Shadowing Test Sources and Dependencies
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar

task testJar(type: ShadowJar) {
    classifier = 'tests'
    from sourceSets.test.output
    configurations = [project.configurations.testRuntime]
}
```

This way you'll be 100% sure that your final JAR will have all the needed dependencies to run without hassling with `collect`s.

And don't forget to specify the main class, like described [here](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/configuration/#configuring-the-jar-manifest).

```
shadowJar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'a.b.C' // FQDN!
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not able to use Shadowjar. Im am actually getting all my dependencies from a private url within my job

Comment: Well, I see you have `repositories { mavenCentral() }` in your config, so that sounds weird. Also, I see `plugins` block in your script, so plugins most probably are resolved from [Gradle Plugin repository](https://plugins.gradle.org/). **Unless** you have some black magic in your `settings.gradle`, which I doubt. Nevertheless, shadow plugin has nothing to do with the source of your dependencies and its resolution process, it's all about creating a resulting artifact with all the dependencies inside.

Comment: I figured out how to use it but now im getting a ***java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/ITestListener***

Comment: Seems like your fat JAR (shadow JAR) is not that fat and missing some classes. Check its content and configs. If you're using the Shadow JAR plugin, are you sure you run `shadowJar` task (or `testJar`)? Check the JAR file you run — there may be multiple artifacts in the outputs.

Comment: I had to switch all my dependencies to ***testCompile*** and ***compile***  because i found that there's and issue going with shadowJar and the new gradle implementation but im still having the same issues as before. I CANNOT :(